# How to get option value in database

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="MCQ1_1" name="q1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" value="1" for="MCQ1_1"> Option A </label>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="MCQ1_2" name="q1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" value="2" for="MCQ1_2">Option B</label>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="MCQ1_3" name="q1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" value="3" for="MCQ1_3">Option C</label>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check">
      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="MCQ1_4" name="q1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" value="4" for="MCQ1_4">Option D</label>
    </div>
```

This is a set of 4 options to a question.
 We need to get the selected answer into a database

```
[err,result] = await to(db.query('insert into result(reg_no,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,essay1,essay2,essay3) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[req.session.reg, req.body.q1.value, req.body.q2.value, req.body.q3, req.body.q4, req.body.q5, req.body.q6, req.body.q7, req.body.q8, req.body.q9, req.body.q10, req.body.essay1, req.body.essay2, req.body.essay3]));
```

But for no matter what option you click, you just recieve an 'ON' on the database. I want the option value to come.
Eg. If i select option B, then i should have 2 in the database.

Comment: add the value attribute in the input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input should have value

```
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1" id="MCQ1_2" name="q1">
```

remove it from label

Comment: post complete code, how you're sending and receiving data

Answer (score 0):

YOU SHOULD ADD VALUE ATTRIBUTE TO EACH INPUT TYPE.
FOR e.g

```
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="MCQ1_2" name="q1"        value="ur_ans">
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your exact method for extracting and putting the form value into the database?